# Only few iPhone 6s - failed to return after waiting 10 seconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

I am having this really really strange issue where only on one iPhone 6s running iOS 9.0.2 (my friend's), my app basically just freezes right after launching. Sometimes the app works a few seconds and completely freezes. Sometimes it freezes right after launching.

```
015-10-13 17:47:02.542 Musicbot[1638:1057192] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:resource:didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2015-10-13 17:47:12.544 Musicbot[1638:1057192] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:resource:didFinishLoadingFromDataSource:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

The error makes no sense because my app has no webViews. I even searched for UIWebView or didFinishLoadingFromDataSource in the entire app and zero hits in my app code. It's a pure objective c app.

---

I have tried removing almost all functionality of the app and it still freezes after a few seconds. I look at the memory and as soon as it freezes, it starts climbing up in 30MB chunks. It even reaches around 900 MB when it's killed by iOS. (iPhone 6s has 2gigs memory I believe).

After all this, I bought myself an iPhone 6s and tested the app on it. It works perfectly find on mine with no issues. Then I upgraded it to 9.0.2 and it still works perfectly find on it.
I have thousands of downloads and no one has reported this issue - though I am not sure if reviews from iPhone 6s or 9.0.2 are coming in yet at app store? So I am pretty much lost on what's happening. 
My app so far has worked perfectly fine on 4s, iPhone 5 (my old one) and 5s and iPhone 6 which my brother has. Only my friend's iPhone 6s is having the issue as far as I know. 
How should I even go about troubleshooting this?

Comment: Start by working out could be different about your friends phone. Have you tried a completely clean install? Wiped docs, user defaults, keychain for your app? Is his phone jailbroken? Are other apps running that could cause issues? Restarted the device? If you have removed all functionality like you said, then perhaps something your app has stored on the device is corrupt.

Comment: @BeauYoung he downloaded the app straight from the app store and his phone is brand new and never connected to my mac / Xcode etc. So his is a fresh copy of the app and didn't have anything cached. It's 6s running 9.0.2 which is not jailbroken as there is none available. It's literally a completely clean install. Yes we restarted the device too. All I can think of now is if the model number he has is having the issue because I was reading on how apple manufactures the phone at different places, but I am not sure about this.

Comment: Hey @PranoyC have you found any solution for this, because my app is failed to launch in every iPhone6s but not in any other iOS devices like iPhone4,5,6 and 6+.

Comment: @ParthMehta I even went out and bought myself a 6s and was not able to reproduce the issue. Same with my brother, I couldn't reproduce the issue on his 6s too. I was able to reproduce it literally on only 1 device in person and 1 bad review from hundreds of good app store review which faced the same issue. what I did find out was that the apple store guy told me that there have been a very few defective devices and suggested my friend exchange his phone for another one. You should definitely try testing on other iPhone 6s to see if it's a faulty device. If you need me to test, let me know!

Comment: I tried with different different iPhone6s devices and it fails to launch the application. so i am very confused why it happens.

Comment: hmmm, then that might be a different issue than mine. If it's freezing at the same place every time? doing the same thing? or at different places?

Try using Instruments with Allocations and maybe the time profiler too to see what you see or if you find the memory / cpu usage keep growing?